# Google play console warnings

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm getting these two warnings when I tried to update my app in Google Play Console:

> unknown validation
> VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WRONG_LANGUAGE

> unknown validation
> VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_FULL_DESCRIPTION_WRONG_LANGUAGE

What are these warnings and how can i fix them?

Comment: Which are the short and long description on your Play Store app profile? It seems like there is something wrong there.

Comment: Check if the description language is correct.

Comment: Add your short and full description content under tag **<en_us>**You content here**</en_us>**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was that Google uses Google translate to translate all the descriptions. In my case, Google had confused Bulgarian with Russian